# Trident maple leaf curl with some dark tips

Tags: trees, plant-health, bonsai, maple

Two maples have just come out of dormancy sprouting deformed leaves. They are nearly all curled and some have shrivelled and died with black edges.

Any idea what it could be?

They are outside mainly in shade. Direct sun is not an issue. Its warm temparatures, and I cannot see any bugs.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please confirm these are bonsai.  Is it spring where you live?  Do you get a winter?  What do you do with these plants during their dormancy?

Comment: It is Spring. It is a bonsai. It wintered properly. They have been outside during winter. It never really goes lower than 8deg celcius.

Comment: Its since lost all its leaves. In an attempt to discover the problem, I went through many different things, one being submerging the pot for 15 minutes. I found tens and tens of worms dead in the water.

Comment: That could be the source of the problem

Comment: Update. The tree is dead. :(

Comment: Patience, if there is still live bark it might come back.  Make a small cut in the bark, if you see white or green something is still alive

Answer (score 1):

Has there been enough time for these leaves to 'unfurl' to their mature form? There is one disease to be considering; Anthracnose.  A fungal disease.  Before any treatment we need to verify exactly what your plants truly have.[Anthracnose on shade trees](http://extension.psu.edu/pests/plant-diseases/all-fact-sheets/anthracnose-on-shade-treeshttp://)

Please send another picture of one of the same views you've sent.  This article has a few simple signs you need to look for and send pictures of what you find. Closeups of the underside of the leaf, pictures of vegetative buds not in leaf, some of the twig ends, pruning cuts.  Do you have a loupe? (magnifying glass without handle 10X).  This will have to entail a few more pictures and investigation on your part. This is one of the maples least susceptible to disease. Is this a Bonsai?

Comment: Could you please send more information?  At least another picture...

Comment: Yes its bonsai.